# Fixed position div within a fluid grid parent wrapper?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fluid-layout, grid-system

I've built a website using a fluid 12 column grid. I'd like to fix the position of one of the divs in the right hand column when it reaches the top of the page (using [StickyJs](http://stickyjs.com/) or some equivalent)

However when the fixed position is applied the div is taken out of the DOM and it completely breaks the grid structure as the div looses its parent formatting.

https://jsfiddle.net/k4r00au0/

```
position: fixed;
```

Is there a way to maintain the divs position and size after fixing its scroll position?

I've tried:

```
width: inherit;
```

to no avail

Thank in advance for any help, abit stumped with this one!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this through javascript, by setting the width manually.

```
var fixed = $('#fixed'),
    container = fixed.closest('.inheritw');

$(window).on('resize',function(){
    fixed.width( container.width() );
}).trigger('resize')
```

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/k4r00au0/1/